# Serial to USB aggregation with Pi

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, usb, serial

I'd like to aggregate 4 serial devices to a single USB device (a rPi zero with only 2 UART).

So far, I've been able to design the following schematic but I'm not sure of the components used nor if the wiring is correct.

Could you tell me if I've made any mistake or not ?

[image]

Comment: a quad serial to USB adapter would be simpler

Comment: `Could you help me with that ?` is not a question about electronics design ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: The question is why you want to do this. It might be possible to multiplex one UART with four devices. And depending on which Rpi model you have, it might already have 4+ UARTs so nothing is needed.

Comment: I've got a Pi zero and it only has 2 UART. I'd like to use it to share over wifi serial devices (industrial machines).

Comment: A slight modification of the comment from @jsotola: "a quad serial to **Ethernet/wifi** adapter would be simpler."

Comment: @Manitoba What you are designing might cost more than another Pi Zero. With two Pi Zeros you have 4 UARTs. Another solution, buy an USB hub and four USB UART cables. Or a product that already does what you want, with industrial specs and robustness, not at hobbyist specs and quality.

Comment: Im going to drop this link: https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005005210488280.html ... I might add: WIFI is a big NoNo in machinery due to uncontrollable packet-loss, latency and connection break-down. A ethernet outlet is close-by almost everywhere these days.

Comment: @Manitoba there's single chips that can do 4 UARTs to USB CDC without problem, so I'd say your whole approach seems, at the very least, very complicated for what it does. But I don't know what you actually want to *achieve*

Comment: @MarcusMüller Could you share me a link or the name of this single chip please ?

Comment: Can't right now, look for the larger ftdi chips. Else, a mid range microcontroller with for uarts and a full speed USB peripheral built in would do as well, but you'd end up needing firmware